Typecast to timestamp from stringtype in Pyspark
How can I typecast a string type to timestamp in Pyspark
The stringtype data is like this 2024-04-02-19.02.20.000000. I need this column data in timestamp.
Column is of type String, need to convert in timestamp

You can use to_timestamp function with a custom pattern to suite your format:
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "2023-04-15-19.20.20.000000"), (2, "2023-10-02-19.02.20.000000"), (3, "2024-04-02-19.02.20.000000")], ("id", "dt"))

df.withColumn("pdt", to_timestamp("dt", "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS")).show()

+---+--------------------+-------------------+
| id|                  dt|                pdt|
+---+--------------------+-------------------+
|  1|2023-04-15-19.20....|2023-04-15 19:20:20|
|  2|2023-10-02-19.02....|2023-10-02 19:02:20|
|  3|2024-04-02-19.02....|2024-04-02 19:02:20|
+---+--------------------+-------------------+

